# Image edit filter in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am developing a project (kinda like CamScanner) where I take an image and on the fly crop it and edit it and save it to my device memory. I chose to do it in xamarin forms because of 1 source maintenance. I have managed to take the image using Xam.Plugin.Media and crop that image using ImageCropper.Forms plugins. Now, I cant seem to find any good plugins that can edit my image (Filters like Black and White, Magic Color, Grayscale). Can anyone guide me to choose which plugin is the best there is for the filter? I am focusing mainly on Android and iOS at the moment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, I am sure you will have to do this natively, Xamarin forms have no plugins to help you with this(That I am aware of!)

Answer (score 1):

As of today, there is no plugin available to apply color filters for Xamarin.Forms. The closest thing would be using [SkiaSharp Color Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/color-filters) and define you own [Color Matrices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-translate-image-colors), which is not quite user friendly.